# Using FullerCalendar in Angular 8 , how to add an event clicking on a date on the calendar?

Tags: angular, date, events, calendar

I have the fullercalendar integrated in Angular 8 project, I can not seem to find a way to add event clicking on a date.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It took me 30 seconds to find this in the docs - is this what you're after - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular#emitted-events?

Comment: Well I did try this  but I needed some further help to add an 'appointment' to the calendar after clicking the date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dateClick` handler.

```
<full-calendar (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"></full-calendar>
```

In your controller:

```
handleDateClick(arg) { // handler method
    alert(arg.dateStr);
}
```

---

Full documentation:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular#emitted-events